# Python: How to tell if an element in a list contains a certain number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, boolean

For example, if I type:

```
li=[33];
3 in li
```

I get:

```
False
```

If I check that 33 is there, of course I get "True". 
How can I correctly check for the presence of the digit within the list element?

Comment: what programming language U use?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Python as the title says.

Comment: oh yes, sorry I miss that information. You can also add python TAG to question

Comment: Thank you, added the python tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple approach is this one:

```
li = [33,44,55]
['3' in str(x) for x in li]
```

This gives

```
[True, False, False]
```

By using a list comprehension we go through the elements of `li`, convert the value to a `str`. Then it is checked if '3' (or whatever value you desire) is in the string.
The result of this operation is a list of the length of `li` with values `True` or `False`.

This also works for numbers of n digits, i.e.

```
['31' in str(x) for x in [1314]]
```

also returns true.

Here we implicitly assumed that all elements of `li` can be casted as strings.

Comment: I am not aware of anything that **cannot** be cast to `str`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis yes, that seems to be true. I was not exactly sure if there may be some exotic cases where this is not true.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a functional approach for comparison:

```
lst = [5, 1, 23, 6, 33, 31, 15]

res = list(map(lambda x: '3' in x, map(str, lst)))

# [False, False, True, False, True, True, False]
```